# Solving $\Delta u=f(u)$

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, partial-differential-equations

I am currently reading Partial Differential Equations on Riemannian manifold without boundary. I want to consider a PDE of the form $$\Delta u=f(u).$$

Can anyone tell me a reference which contains possibilities of solutions depending on $f$.